# Problem with name pointer when calling a high score function. All names get replaced by most recent name. Can't use malloc

Tags: c, pointers, game-development, pic32

When I run `high_score` twice, the `display_high_score` function displays the scores correctly, but displays the name I inputted the second time for both. Basically, `render_string(displayBuffer, name, 28 + 14 * i, 24)` seemingly has the same name for both.

```
struct high_score {
    char *name;
    int score;
};

void highscore(int *score, uint8_t *displayBuffer, struct high_score *high_score_arr) {
    uint8_t original_switch = getsw();
    char *alphabet_str = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int highScrExit = 0;
    int first_box_num = 0, second_box_num = 0, third_box_num = 0, fourth_box_num = 0, fifth_box_num = 0, sixth_box_num = 0;
    int box_num_arr[6] = { first_box_num, second_box_num, third_box_num, fourth_box_num, fifth_box_num, sixth_box_num };
    char name_letter_array[8] = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '\0' };
    int box_number = 0;
    while (!highScrExit) {
        clearBuffer(displayBuffer);
        uint8_t buttons = getBTNs();
        uint8_t switches = getsw();
        if (buttons & 0x1) {
            box_number = (box_number + 1) % 6;
            delayms(20);
        }
        if (buttons & 0x2) {
            if (box_number > 0) {
                box_number--;
            } else {
                box_number = 5;
            }
            delayms(20);
        }

        if (buttons & 0x8) {
            box_num_arr[box_number]++; //Increment the letter for box we're on by one, meaning that [a] will go to [b]
            name_letter_array[box_number] = alphabet_str[box_num_arr[box_number] % 27]; //change the letter in the name to that letter
            delayms(20);
        }
        if (buttons & 0x4) {
            if (box_num_arr[box_number] > 0) {
                box_num_arr[box_number]--;
            } else if (box_num_arr[box_number] <= 0) {
                box_num_arr[box_number] = 26;
            }
            name_letter_array[box_number] = alphabet_str[box_num_arr[box_number] % 27];
            delayms(20);
        }

        if ((!(original_switch & 0x8) && switches & 0x8) || ((original_switch & 0x8) && !(switches & 0x8))) {
            struct high_score player_high_scr = { name_letter_array, *score };
            int i;
            for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (player_high_scr.score > (&high_score_arr[i])->score){
                    high_score_arr[i + 1] = high_score_arr[i];
                    high_score_arr[i] = player_high_scr;
                }
            }
            highScrExit = 1;
            display_high_score_screen(displayBuffer, high_score_arr);
        }
        render_triangle(displayBuffer, 52, 28 - 4 * box_number);
        int j;
        render_switch(displayBuffer, 80, 28);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "save  ", 80, 20);
        //For loop not working for some reason? It's ugly but works
        render_button(displayBuffer, 80 + 9, 28);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "up    ", 80 + 9, 20);
        render_button(displayBuffer, 80 + 9+9, 28);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "down  ", 80 + 9+9, 20);
        render_button(displayBuffer, 80 + 9+9+9, 28);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "left  ", 80 + 9+9+9, 20);
        render_button(displayBuffer, 80 + 9+9+9+9, 28);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "right  ", 80 + 9+9+9+9, 20);

        render_string(displayBuffer, "score ", 5, 25);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "enter ", 28, 26);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "name ", 35, 24);
        render_string(displayBuffer, name_letter_array, 45, 28);
        render_score(displayBuffer, score, 15, 20);
        displayUpdate(displayBuffer);
    }
}

void display_high_score_screen(uint8_t *displayBuffer, struct high_score *high_score_arr) {
    int mainMenuExit = 0;
    while (!mainMenuExit) {
        clearBuffer(displayBuffer);
        uint8_t buttons = getBTNs();
        if (buttons & 0x8) {
            mainMenuExit = 1;
            delayms(30);
        }
        int i;
        render_string(displayBuffer, "top  ", 5, 22);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "scores ", 12, 25);
        render_button(displayBuffer, 100, 28);
        render_string(displayBuffer, "quit ", 100, 20);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int number = i + 1;
            char* name = (&high_score_arr[i])->name;
            int score = (&high_score_arr[i])->score;
            render_score(displayBuffer, &number, 28 + 14 * i, 30);
            if (*name != '\0' && score != -1) {
                render_string(displayBuffer, name, 28 + 14 * i, 24);
                render_score(displayBuffer, &score, 35 + 14 * i, 18);
            }
        }
        displayUpdate(displayBuffer);
    }
}

//Call the high_score function like this:
        if (gameOver) {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (score > (&high_score_arr[j])->score) {
                    j = 5;
                    highscore(&score, displayBuffer, high_score_arr);
                }
            }

//This is the part of the code that assigns name:

            struct high_score player_high_scr = { name_letter_array, *score };
            int i;
            for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (player_high_scr.score > (&high_score_arr[i])->score) {
                    high_score_arr[i+1] = high_score_arr[i];
                    high_score_arr[i] = player_high_scr;
                }
            }
            highScrExit = 1;
            display_high_score_screen(displayBuffer, high_score_arr);

//I should point out that this is how I initialize the array:

void init_high_scr_arr() {
    int i;
    char *null;
    *null = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        high_score_arr[i].name = null;
        high_score_arr[i].score = -1;
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of things, making highscore return a `high_score` struct, putting that in `display_high_score` and calling it. I've tried making `high_score.name` into an array instead of a pointer, I've tried saving the result in some global variable, etc. Nothing changes the result. All names are the same as the last name I entered in `high_score`.

Comment: The usual reason is that they all point to the same source string buffer. There is a lot of irrelevant code to look through, though.

Comment: You haven't shown how you assign the `name` member. But it sounds like you're using the same input buffer in a loop, and just assigning that buffer pointer. You need to make a copy of the input. Use the `strdup()` function if available, otherwise it's a simple 2-line function to write yourself.

Comment: Or if `strdup()` (which performs dynamic memory allocation) is disallowed along with `malloc()`, then you may just need to declare a large-enough array of large-enough arrays of `char`, so that you can store a different name in each element.

Comment: _The problem is that i can't use malloc in the environment i'm working with._ Why??? Is this some [stupid] academic assignment? Or, that `pic32` (or just about any PIC processor) has an anemic amount of memory in multiple discontiguous banks? What about: `void * mymalloc(size_t len) { static size_t off = 0; static unsigned char arena[1024 * 1024]; unsigned char *ptr = NULL; if ((off + len) < sizeof(arena)) { ptr = &arena[off]; off += len; } ; return ptr; }`

Comment: @CraigEstey It is pic32 that doesn't allow for stdlib

Comment: @Adrian pic32 doesn't _have_ enough memory to support much of a full library. The pic processor was designed circa 1975 when memory was a premium. In order to save some bits in instructions, it used banked memory. No PIC should be used in any new design. _Any_ other SoC is better: Arduino, Rpi, stm32, esp32, atmel, AVR, arm. Since Microchip acquired Atmel, it has deprecated PIC in favor of AVR

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary code here, and what is provided can't be compiled. Provide a [mcve]. The process of paring down what you have to a _complete, minimal_ example that compiles and runs to demonstrate the issue can lead to a solution, and if that doesn't work it will give potential answerers a better chance at helping. _"I've tried making `high_score.name` into an array...."_ Yes, that is a good idea if `malloc` is unavailable. Where is that code?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot dynamically create the space for the name you could create the name space in the high_score struct, changing it to something like `char name[8]` to match the size of `name_letter_array`. Then when you store the high score in you will have to copy the string from `name_letter_array` into your high score struct `name`, not just pass a pointer to `name_letter_array`.